# add searchbar in UItoolbar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

i want to know is this possible to add a searchbar in UItoolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a quick look and while interface builder will let you do it, when you try to save a warning pops up a warning saying the following "UISearchBars are not supported in UIBarButtonItems in non-iPad documents".  That being said, it might be possible to make your own view that looks and works like a UIToolbar that does allow a UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest:

`navItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: m_searchBar] autorelease];`

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error stating:

```
 UISearchBars are not supported in UIBarButtonItems in non-iPad documents
```

adding a `UISearchBar` to a view within a `UIBarButtonItem` worked for me.